# Spark sql with hive table delta support

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

As for now the latest version of `Spark` (2.1.0) lists unsupported major functionality of `Hive` like:

> Tables with buckets: bucket is the hash partitioning within a Hive table partition. Spark SQL doesn’t support buckets yet.

It means the `Hive` tables which have bucketed column structure won't be loaded as `DataFrame` processed properly. There is some workaround to achieve such functionality via `JDBC`, temp tables and etc. The main question how achieve full control using `Spark SQL` on tables which materialized with deltas ?